# Geforce 770 gtx reaching 95+ degrees

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, temperature

Hi guys!

I've been playing Assassin's Creed IV a lot these days, I used nearly maximum video settings and my computer's temperature was looking good ( both CPU and GPU ).
Yesterday I started playing Guild Wars 2 and I'm having troble with my GPU's temperature, it is reaching 95+ degrees. The CPU temps are just fine ( max of 85 ).
Do you guys have any idea if this is normal and, if it's not, how can I fix it?

  PC config
- CPU - Intel i7 4770
- GPU - Geforce 770 gtx
- PSU - Coursair 750HX
- MOB - B85M-G
- Windows 8.1

To check the temperatures I used a software called OpenHardwareMonitor.

Thank you!

Comment: Couple of questions before I can try and assist: - Have you installed any new drivers/patches which could explain the extra workload and cause heat? - Any new hardware which could have changed airflow at all? - No blockages on the fans, cables hanging over the front of the fans? - Any recent impacts on the base unti which could have dislodged a dan or heatsink? - Are there any rattling or whirring noises which could be indicating a bearing thats on its last legs?

Comment: How fast is the fan on the GPU running at?

Comment: From my experience, GPU load under GW2 is "spiky". I manage fans with speedfan, and once in a while, fan rush to 100% during 5seconds and then back down. meaning temperature does the same.

Comment: Sorry taking so long to reply guys.
Fazer87, no new drivers/patches, no new hardware too. I checked all the fans and they're fine, there's nothing blocking them.
There were no impacts and I didné hear any noises.
The way the computer is assembled is quite strange actually, the PSU and the GPU have their fans in front of each other, maybe there's a problem because of that, not sure. ( The PSU stays at the bottom of the computer's cabinet ).
Ramhound, the fan is running at =~ 2100 rpm.
Kwaio, yes thats true, it reaches 96 degrees only for a short period of time.
Thank you guys (: